# ADC in STM32F103 drops ouput voltage from unity buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, stm32, voltage

I'm building a signal analyzer based on STM32F103RB6 placed on a noname board with the following schematics:
[image]
I'm trying to normalize the AC input signal initially centered at 0V. The amplitude is 2.5V. So basically I'm trying to shift the signal and center the signal around 1.7V to use it in ADC. To test the schematics I'm using an oscilloscope with a built-in generator. The prototype is built using LM358 dual op-amp.

Here is the schematic I'm using to normalize the signal:
[image]

The input is configured as follows:
[image]

And here is what I get in POINT_B when the ADC is disabled:
[image]

The problem appears if I enable the ADC on the microcontroller (connect op-amp output to ADC pin). In such case the signal in POINT_B becomes the following:
[image]

I'm wondering what is even going on and why does the ADC drop the input voltage? All the source code is available at https://github.com/KapitonovRoman/TimerBasedAdcFFT. Basically it is a DMA enabled ADC which is configured to be triggered by a timer with a 48kHz frequency.

If instead of an ADC pin I connect a 220 Ohm resistor as a load, here is what the oscilloscope outputs:
[image]

Using a potentiometer I've figured out that the same oscillogram can be obtained in case the potentiometer is set to 28 Ohm, which means the resistance of ADC port is 28 Ohm.

The ADC pin (PORTB, PIN_0) is configured as an ADC input:
[image]

When connecting a potentiometer to the ADC pin (to test it) it gives correct values depending on the input voltage from a potentiometer:
[image]

Well, it appeared that the pin I was using is broken.

Comment: Off the top of my head...look for clamping diodes somewhere unexpected or something 1V on the other side of the ESD diodes inside the MCU.

Comment: take the CPU out of the equation, just put a resistor on the op-amp output, does it do the same thing?

Comment: It's clipping at 1v?  What is the max input of the A2D?

Comment: @DKNguyen No, the output from unity buffer is 0-3.4V, the op-amp is powered from a 5V pin on the board

Comment: The only source of ~1V I can think of is the ADC's internal reference but I am not entirely sure it would cause such clamping behaviour because I did not think it was connected in such a way inside the MCU that could cause such a thing. Regardless, did you set up your ADC to properly use your Vdda-Vssa as a reference and not the internal 1.2V reference?

Comment: @Aaron I've connected a 220 Ohm resistor as a load and added the oscillogram to the post. It clips the sine at 3V.

Comment: I don't really want to question your opamp diagram since you provided scope graphs that aren't gnarly, but  is the the U1 output supposed to be connected to the non-inverting input? How does it not saturate?

Comment: @DKNguyen oh, that's a typo! Sorry.

Comment: @Aaron ok, so I've connected a potentiometer and obtained the same graph without connecting the ADC pin. The potentiometer is set to 28 Ohm. Given 28 Ohm load, the signal is clipped at 1V.

Comment: Is the ADC pin correctly configured as an input rather than a GPIO output? You can also temporarily connect it to another spare ADC input (mod software to match) to work around possible pin damage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond well, apparently. Before connecting op-amp output to the pin I've tested it with a potentiometer. The ADC conversion result is being output on a TFT screen. And it does give the values between 0 and 4096 if I spin the potentiometer. I've added a screenshot and a photo to the post.

Comment: Measure the ADC input voltage on the scope while you spin that potentiometer - what voltage corresponds to 2048, 4095?

Comment: @BrianDrummond oh my god, you were so right. I've measured the voltage for different values displayed on the screen. And the port appeared to be broken. I've switched to PORTB PIN_1 and the voltage does not drop and everything is working like a charm. If you wanna put that as an answer I will accept it, and basically the issue is resolved. Thanks once again!

Comment: well ... if you got 4096 on screen at 1V in, check the ADC voltage reference and/or gain settings. It may be there is input protection that clips above the selected Vref (see @DKNguyen's earlier comment). If that's wrong, the port may not be broken, just mis-configured.